# How to display a fourth quadrant with numbers?

Tags: tables, axis

How can i display following picture within LaTeX. 
I don't even know how to properly describe what I see.
Please help me out of my misery!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This can be drawn with environment `picture` (or with TikZ, `pstricks`, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a `matrix of math nodes` from [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells]{
           f & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 1       \\
           1 & 3 & 0 & 2       \\
           2 &                 \\
           3 &                 \\
             &                 \\
       };
       \draw[->] (M-2-2.north west)-- ++(2,0) node[above right]{$x$};
       \draw[->] (M-2-2.north west)-- ++(0,-2) node[below left ]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]